# Matrix Subtraction Confusion (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I'm nearly done with a program that adds, subtracts, and scales two matrices. I've created two test cases for each, and added error messages for when two matrices are not the same size, standard protocol. However, I've run into a issue with my second subtraction case. Here's the two two-dimensional arrays:

```
int[][] a = {{1,2},{3,4}};
int[][] b = {{2,3},{5,7}};
```

And here is the subtraction method, call, and println respectively:

```
public static int[][] subtraction(int[][] arr1, int[][] arr2){
        int rows1 = arr1.length;
        int rows2 = arr2.length;
        int columns1 = arr1[0].length;
        int columns2 = arr2[0].length;
        if (rows1 != rows2 || columns1 != columns2){
            System.out.print("Matrices are not the same size, please try again.");
            return null;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < rows1; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < columns1; j++){
                arr1[i][j] -= arr2[i][j];
            }
        }
        return arr1;
    }
```

---

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(subtraction(b, a)));
```

---

```
[[1, 1], [2, 3]]
```

Checks out, right? So why does this...

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(subtraction(a, b)));
```

...println this?

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

I've done a lot of digging into array documentation and stack overflow and I have never seen anything like this. The program simply prints the first array instead of completing the calculation. Am I missing something here?

Thank you for understanding my plight.

Comment: When I run `subtraction(a, b)`, I get `[[-1, -1], [-2, -3]]`. What else did you run? Remember, you are actually *modifying* `arr1`. That you also return it just makes printing easier.

Comment: Java is pass by value.  The reference pointing to the first matrix is immutable, but its state is not.  Better to create a new instance, load the difference into it, and return the new instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get [[-1, -1], [-2, -3]], which is correct, subtraction changes the first argument so running

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(subtraction(b, a)));
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(subtraction(a, b)));
```

[[1, 1], [2, 3]]
[[0, 1], [1, 1]]

So maybe you have changed a or before calling subtraction(a, b)?

Comment: I'm an idiot. Duh! Thank you for your help, this was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you want:

```
public class Matrix {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] a = {{1,2},{3,4}};
        int[][] b = {{2,3},{5,7}};
        int [][] result = subtraction(b, a);
        System.out.println(toString(result));
        result = subtraction(a, b);
        System.out.println(toString(result));
    }

    private static String toString(int[][] result) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("{");
        for (int i = 0; i < result[0].length; ++i) {
            builder.append("[");
            for (int j = 0; j < result[i].length; ++j) {
                builder.append(result[i][j]);
                if (j < result[i].length-1) {
                    builder.append(",");
                }
            }
            builder.append("]");
        }
        builder.append("}");
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public static int[][] subtraction(int[][] arr1, int[][] arr2){
        int rows1 = arr1.length;
        int rows2 = arr2.length;
        int columns1 = arr1[0].length;
        int columns2 = arr2[0].length;
        if (rows1 != rows2 || columns1 != columns2){
            System.out.print("Matrices are not the same size, please try again.");
            return null;
        }
        int [][] result = new int[rows1][columns1];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows1; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < columns1; j++){
                result[i][j] = arr1[i][j] - arr2[i][j];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! I'll save this for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you are seeing is that your subtraction method is modifying the values inside of the Array object that you are passing it (array1). When you call the method for a second time, you are now passing in a modified version of the array.You can fix this by creating a local copy of the arr1 parameter inside of your subtraction method like this

```
public static int[][] subtraction(int[][] arr1, int[][] arr2){
    int rows1 = arr1.length;
    int rows2 = arr2.length;
    int columns1 = arr1[0].length;
    int columns2 = arr2[0].length;
    if (rows1 != rows2 || columns1 != columns2){
        System.out.print("Matrices are not the same size, please try again.");
        return null;
    }
    // Create copies of the input parameter arrays to prevent modifying the origional
    int[][] copy1 = copyOf(arr1);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows1; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < columns1; j++){
            copy1[i][j] -= arr2[i][j];
        }
    }
    return copy1;
}

public static int[][] copyOf(int[][] origional){
    int[][] copiedArray = new int[origional.length][origional[0].length];
    for(int i=0; i<origional.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<origional[i].length; j++){
            int x = origional[i][j];
            copiedArray[i][j] = x;
        }
    }
    return copiedArray;
}
```

In your code, calling

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(subtraction(b, a)));
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(subtraction(a, b)));
```

Is equivalent to calling

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(subtraction({{2,3},{5,7}}, {{1,2},{3,4}})));
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(subtraction({{1,2},{3,4}}, {{1,1},{2,3}}))); // notice that the b array has been modified
```

When you are assuming that it is equivalent to calling

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(subtraction({{2,3},{5,7}}, {{1,2},{3,4}})));
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(subtraction({{1,2},{3,4}}, {{2,3},{5,7}}))); // here the b array has it's original values
```

For a better understanding on why this happens, see the following excerpt:

> When you pass an object variable into a method, you must keep in mind that you’re passing the object reference, and not the actual object itself. Remember that a reference variable holds bits that represent (to the underlying VM) a way to get to a specific object in memory (on the heap). More importantly, you must remember that you aren’t even passing the actual reference variable, but rather a copy of the reference variable. A copy of a variable means you get a copy of the bits in that variable, so when you pass a reference variable, you’re passing a copy of the bits representing how to get to a specific object. In other words, both the caller and the called method will now have identical copies of the reference; thus, both will refer to the same exact (not a copy) object on the heap. **Kathy Sierra & Bert Bates. “OCA/OCP Java SE 7 Programmer I & II Study Guide (Exams 1Z0-803 & 1Z0-804).**